# when I run " flutter build aot --debug " error?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

when I run "flutter build aot  --debug "is error. 
android-arm does not support AOT compilation.
Building AOT snapshot in debug mode (android-arm)...
Snapshotting exited with non-zero exit code: 1

Comment: check you have installed flutter correctly.

Comment: my Flutter version :

Flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7a4c33425d (9 weeks ago) • 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
Engine • revision 52c7a1e849
Tools • Dart 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

Comment: "flutter build aot --release"  can run OK

Answer (score 3):

There are two mode of Dart build: JIT & AOT.

AOT is for release mode by default in flutter build

BTW: `flutter build aot` is deprecated, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49562